# Sending a POST request with FILE using in XAMARIN C#

Tags: c#, file, xamarin, post, httpclient

looking on the web, I saw a little bit how to POST a 'file' and therefore, I wrote my code in this way:

```
        var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes((string)fPath);

        //create new HttpClient and MultipartFormDataContent and add our file, and StudentId
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        ByteArrayContent baContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);
        content.Add(baContent, "img", fPath);

        StringContent emailText = new StringContent(lbl_email.Text);
        content.Add(emailText, "email");

        string url = "http://192.168.178.77/TestLoginURL/api/updateUserImage.php";
        //upload MultipartFormDataContent content async and store response in response var
        var response =
            await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        //read response result as a string async into json var
        var responsestr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

now the problem is another ... this is my API code:

```
<?php
$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    //getting values
    $img = $_FILES['img']['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    //including the db operation file
    require_once '../includes/DbOperation.php';

    $db = new DbOperation();

    $target = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/TestLoginURL/images/".basename($img);

    //inserting values
    if($db->updateImage((String)basename($img),$email)){
        $response['error']=false;
        $response['message']='Image added successfully - test fileName = '.(String)basename($img);
    }else{
        $response['error']=true;
        $response['message']='Could not add image';
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        /*$response['error']=false;
        $response = "Image uploaded successfully";*/
    }else{
        $response['error']=true;
        $response = "Failed to upload image";
    }
}else{
    $response['error']=true;
    $response['message']='You are not authorized';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

With Postman it works perfectly, updates the name of the image in the database and physically inserts the image in the designated path and the response message for example is this: {"error": false, "message": "Image added successfully - test fileName = trollolollo.png"}

[image: postman]

[image: dbrow]

Now, the app saves the file in the right repository but does NOT UPDATE the name of the 'image' in the database ... BUT strangely, the "response" message in the debugger also correctly shows the name of the FILE ... So I just don't understand where I'm wrong ... Could someone help me with the code please? Thanks

[image: xamarinvs debugger]

OFF_TOPIC: usually, when I have to send only strings, I send a post request written in this way

```
            string url = "http://192.168.178.77/TestLoginURL/api/insertUser.php";

            FormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("nickname", nickname),
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password1),
              new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email)
            });

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            try
            {
                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(url, formContent).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
                throw;
            }
```

but now, being a file and having no experience about it I am having difficulties...
thanks again, I hope someone can help me with the code

Comment: in the Xamarin code, you appear to be setting the "img" parameter to the full path of the file, not just the file name

Comment: yes, this way my API can recognize both the file and the name as you can see in the debuger screenshot ...
I'm wrong? should I try the path alone? And then if there are other files, how else can he choose the right one? how should i change the code? (excuse the large amount of questions but I would like to understand as much as possible XD) @Jason - 
as a solution to the problem I can make 2 different post requests ... one to move the image in the directory and the other to simply change the name in the database table ... but it seems to me a HORRIBLE solution.

Comment: your server does not need to know the entire path, it just cares about the file name

Comment: I changed the code this way 

   "     ByteArrayContent baContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);
                content.Add(baContent, "img", fileName);    "

and thanks, you are right about the path but unfortunately I still have the same problem ... the image is saved in the folder on the server, the debugger returns the correct name even after the query has been made but actually the database is not updated with the name ... :( @Jason

Comment: then you need to debug your PHP code to figure out why the db update does not work

Comment: then i will check here ... but it work if i try the POST with postman :/ @Jason

Comment: I don't know.  That's why you need to debug it.  Compare the server execution for a Postman request to a Xamarin request to see why they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are handling update query correctly ?

Update query will only return false on a failure if you messed up the SQL query or anything like that. So you have to use [mysqli_stmt_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) to see if a row has been updated in your PHP code.

If postman can do it HttpClient must be able to do it too, with the proper configuration.

Try to use all the headers postman is using you are probably missing something, maybe the filename is causing the DB query to fail.

By the way is there any difference between how you handle jpg and png in your server ? you can check that too.

Comment: Thanks @Nicole,I finally managed to solve the problem.
I took the value of the email through a label and even printing the values on PHP also returned the correct value to me ... but in the SQL qry was an empty string (I can't understand why).
All this works if instead of the label, in XAML I put an invisible entry ...

Comment: @Jason this was the function in PHP where I performed the QRY:

     public function updateImage ($ img, $ email) {
         $ stmt = $ this-> conn-> prepare ("UPDATE User SET image =? WHERE email =?");
         $ stmt-> bind_param ("ss", $ img, $ email);
         $ result = $ stmt-> execute ();
         $ Stmt-> close ();
         if ($ result) {
             return true;
         } else {
             return false;
         }
     }